# MySQL UDF function with C truncated result for multi row execution

Tags: mysql, c, user-defined-functions

I am a newbie for MySql udf with C so sorry in advance if this question is so silly. I want to create a MySql udf that takes 2 long and makes some calculations then concat 2 numeric result into a char * but i couldn't achive this in a healty way so far.

As I inspect the issue I noticed that the result truncation is limited with the first rows first parameters length that is so weird. So here is what i tried and could not achieve.

C code for my udf (simplified, calculations excluded)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string.h>

my_bool int_to_string_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message);

void int_to_string_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid);

char *int_to_string(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *result, unsigned long *length, char *is_null, char *error);

my_bool int_to_string_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message) {
    if (args->arg_count != 2 || args->arg_type[0] != INT_RESULT || args->arg_type[1] != INT_RESULT) {
        strcpy(message, "This function takes two long arguments");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void int_to_string_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid) {
}

char *int_to_string(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *result, unsigned long *length, char *is_null, char *error) {
    long a = *((long *) args->args[0]);
    long b = *((long *) args->args[1]);
    sprintf(result, "%ld:%ld", a, b);
    *length = strlen(result);

    return result;
}
```

as i compile that C code with the gcc command below, and copied int_to_string.so to mysql dir

```
gcc -o int_to_string.so -shared int_to_string.c `mysql_config --include` -fPIC
```

then i create the MySQL function with

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS int_to_string;
CREATE FUNCTION int_to_string RETURNS STRING SONAME 'int_to_string.so';
```

after i execute my `int_to_string` function, it has no truncation for single line executions but, when i execute it for a dataset it truncates the result within the first paremeters' length (also it truncates the first row as well).

Here is the example results;

```
SELECT int_to_string(21474836474,9134545)
```

[image: test 1]

```
SELECT int_to_string(21474836474,9134545)
UNION ALL
SELECT int_to_string(100,8)
UNION ALL
SELECT int_to_string(100,91)
```

[image: test 2]

PS: Since the dataset is big and calculations take some time with MySQL function I wanted to create a C udf. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are hitting [max_length](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/8.0/en/adding-loadable-function.html#:%7E:text=unsigned%20int%20max_length), but I am not sure why this is only happening when you have multiple rows in the result set.

> **unsigned int max_length**
>
> The maximum length of the result. The default max_length value differs depending on the result type of the function. For string functions, the default is the length of the longest argument. For integer functions, the default is 21 digits. For real functions, the default is 13 plus the number of decimal digits indicated by initid->decimals. (For numeric functions, the length includes any sign or decimal point characters.)
>
> If you want to return a blob value, you can set max_length to 65KB or 16MB. This memory is not allocated, but the value is used to decide which data type to use if there is a need to temporarily store the data.

Defining max_length in your int_to_string_init function should resolve this -

```
my_bool int_to_string_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message) {
    if (args->arg_count != 2 || args->arg_type[0] != INT_RESULT || args->arg_type[1] != INT_RESULT) {
        strcpy(message, "This function takes two long arguments");
        return 1;
    }

    /*
    ** This will need to be changed to accommodate your real result
    ** 11 digits + : + 11 digits
    */
    initid->max_length = 23;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @nnichols thank you for your reply. You mentioned a nice point but it seems that is not helping too, unfortunately results are same. PS: First I tried max_length 23 then 1000 nothing has changed.

Comment: @CihanUygun What OS/version and MySQL/version are you building this on? I am not seeing the same issues when building on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 64bit with MySQL 8.0.31 (had to change [my_bool to bool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-1.html#mysqld-8-0-1-compiling) as no longer used)

Comment: It is Centos 7.9.2009 (Core) with gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 and MySQL is 8.0.25, is it possible that the issue is related with compiling environment or MySQL environment?

Comment: @CihanUygun you should be getting an error when trying to compile as my_bool no longer exists. This suggests you are compiling against an older version of MySQL.

Comment: Nnichols thank you for that tip, i will try it again according the hint you give me and update with the results. It may take several days since I am a bit busy. Thank you so much.